# Java 7 Class Not Found Exception when calling https

Tags: java, https, urlconnection

We've got some code that works fine in Java 6:

```
    String g = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri="
            + URLEncoder.encode("http://www.bestcricketgame.com/facebook-login/", "UTF-8")
            + "&client_secret=xxxxxxx" 
            + "&code=" + code;

    URL u = new URL(g);
    URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
```

However, after installing java 7 and running the same code we get this:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:86)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:971)
    at tipping.FacebookLogin.processFacebookLogin(FacebookLogin.java:39)
    at tipping.FacebookLoginCallbackServlet.service(FacebookLoginCallbackServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:91)
```

.....

Line 39 is :        URLConnection c = u.openConnection();

The obvious thought is that maybe we should be using HttpsURLConnection, but on the other hand, it doesn't really make sense that we'd get a ClassNotFoundException for not using it, and also a major change like this would surely be documented.  I've searched google and haven't been able to find anything related to this matter.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where did you get your JRE?

Comment: This looks like a corrupted runtime.

Comment: Post your imports. Without that it's impossible to answer this authoritatively.

Comment: @BrianRoach This almost definitely has nothing to do with the imports. We can clearly see that code goes through `URL#openConnection()`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Meh, yeah, I just kind of skimmed over it.

Comment: Tested in a properly installed Java 7 JDK/JRE; this doesn't happen. Voting to close as there's no way to answer this.

Answer (score -2):

Try using java.net.URLConnection as your import.

Comment: Nice answer, really wasn't stated as a comment already or anything

Comment: Came across this because I recently saw someone hit this exception. FYI, the calling code is indirectly referencing it as shown by the question's stacktrace, so this is not the cause.